# How do I set the Provide-Capability header in the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, liferay-7

We use the Apache Felix `maven-bundle-plugin` to generate a manifest for our fragment bundle. This fragment bundle is intended to override resources on a Liferay *host* bundle. The [Liferay DXP documentation](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/overriding-language-keys#find-the-module-and-its-metadata-and-language-keys) specifies that the developer ought to include a `Provide-Capability` header in their manifest to override the host bundle's resources. However, the [Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin documentation](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) does not specify how to do so in the plugin, or whether this is possible.

Is there any way for us to add the `Provide-Capability` header using the Apache Felix `maven-bundle-plugin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `maven-bundle-plugin`, you just put `<Provide-Capability>...</Provide-Capability>` in the plugins configuration making sure to replace `...` with the desired value of the header.

In fact, you can add any of the manifest headers defined in the [OSGi spec](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html). It's [specified in the documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#features) as follows:

> The BND library underlying the plugin defines instructions to direct its behavior. For this Maven plugin, these instructions are issued in the plugin configuration section of the POM file, as was illustrated above. BND recognizes three types of instructions
>
> **1. Manifest headers - Any instruction that starts with a capital letter will appear in the resulting bundle's manifest file; the value for the header will either be copied, augmented, or generated by BND depending on the instruction.**
>
> 2. Variables - Any instruction starting with a lowercase letter is assumed to be a variable in the form of a name-value pair, such as version=3.0, that can be used for property substitution, but is not copied to the manifest.
> 3. Directives - Any instruction starting with a '-' character is considered to be a directive that informs BND to perform some special processing and is not copied to the manifest

Comment: yep, that was it.

Comment: They actually have to be declared in the instructions section of the configuration, not directly in the configuration.